# EnvironmentObject is not notifying changes to views that are subscribed

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

I have this app where I am implementing a logout feature with firebase firestore. What I want to do is detach all my snapshotListeners when the user logs out. I use an environmentObject to observe when the user logged out.

```
class StatusManager: ObservableObject{

@Published var didLogOut: Bool = false

}
```

I inject the object into the environment. Then, I catch the object in every view that has a listener.

```
    @EnvironmentObject var statusManager: StatusManager
```

This is how I plan to detach the listener once the user logs out.

```
        .onAppear(perform: {

        
        if statusManager.didLogOut == false{
            

        notifyListener = db.collectionGroup("resources").whereField("control", isEqualTo: true).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, err) in
            
          //All the functionality
    }
}
        else{
            notifyListener?.remove()
        }
})
```

And this is where the user logs out.

```
                Button(action: {
                
                isLoggedIn = false
                lastLoggedEmail = ""
                lastLoggedUserType = ""
                lastLoggedUserPassword = ""
                statusManager.didLogOut = true

                try? Auth.auth().signOut()
                
                navStack.pop(to: .root)
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Sign Out")
                    .font(Font.custom("Roboto-Light", size: 14))
                
            })
```

The problem is, The code where I use the snapshot listener is never reread once the didLogOut state is changed. Therefore, the snapshot listener is never removed.

Comment: Looks like an architectural issue. If `StatusManager` isn't meant to manage the logged in status, why not create a function on it called `login` or `logout` that does all of the actions related to logging in/out (like adding listeners). Then, instead of managing your logged in state in your view (`isLoggedIn`), make that a `@Published` parameter on your `StatusManager`. You could probably get rid of `didLogOut` altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the view where your *notifyListener* logic is not re-drawn (as in removed from the tree and re-added again) that code will only run once (when it's shown for the first time, since it's an *onAppear* block). If that's the case you can use the *onChange* block instead.

```
.onChange(of: statusManager.didLogOut) { value
       if value == false {
           notifyListener = db.collectionGroup("resources").whereField("control", isEqualTo: true).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, err) in }
       } else {
           notifyListener?.remove()
       }
})
```